# Webpack Server не собирает .js

Tags: javascript, webpack

Webpack-dev-server 2.4.2 не собирает .js (в моем случае это bundle.js). При запуске все выводит в терминал без ошибок, пишет "successful", но результата нет - выводит неизменённый bundle.js
Запрашивая команду webpack, без локального запуска, все отрабатывает без ошибок, сборка происходит. 
Не оставайтесь равнодушными к этому вопросу, на просторах сети эта проблема встречается нередко.

```js
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname),
        publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, './static')
        // path: __dirname + '/bundle'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader'
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

webpack-dev-server имеет зависимость, поскольку bundle.js файл кэшируется и не может обновляться. Проблема решилась установкой плагина html-webpack-plugin со следующими настройками кэша;

```js
plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'), new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'My App',
            filename: 'index.html',
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true
            },
            hash: true
        })
    ]
```

`new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')` относиться к другому плагину.
После установки и настройки сначала запустите webpack, только потом webpack-dev-server